# ionRangeSlider is undefined, unable to update

Tags: jquery, rangeslider

I'd like to reset the ionRangeSlider 'from' value the original when the bootstrap model closes. I'm however unable to reset it because the `rangeSlider`is undefined.

Code:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".order").ionRangeSlider({
            min: 1,
            max: 20,
            type: 'single',
            step: 1,
            prettify: false,
            hasGrid: false,
        });

        $('#settingsModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {

            // Find the range slider jquery element
            var rangeSliderElement = $(this).closest('.well').first('.order');

            // Get the start value
            var startValue = rangeSliderElement.data('from');

            // Get the ion range slider
            var rangeSlider = rangeSliderElement.data("ionRangeSlider");

            // Reset its value
            rangeSlider.update({
                from : startValue
            });
        });
    });
```

I do have multiple ionRangeSliders on my page.

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap was causing some issues, i couldn't use `$(this)` to search for ionRangeSlider in the event.

This works:

```
    var indexModule = $(this).closest('.col-md-3').index();

    // Get the ion range slider
    var rangeSlider = $("#modules .col-md-3").eq(indexModule).find('.order').data("ionRangeSlider");

    // Reset its value
    rangeSlider.reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

I also met with same issue since yesterday and tried various things but nothing good. I was using theme **"themeforest-4021469-metronic-responsive-admin-dashboard-template"** and hence using IonRangeSlider.js from its assets folder.

Just few minutes ago, I overwrite the js content of "ion.rangeSlider.js" with [ionden](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/static/js/ion-rangeSlider/ion.rangeSlider.js) and holaaa.. I am back to senses. :)